# Python plot with annotating arrows

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, figure

I have a python script that plot temperatures. Since some stations are too close, it causes overlap.
I am trying to use annotating arrows to make the values more visible.
Here is an example of a zommed map

[image]

How can I adjust the arrows so that the values stay near the edge (not besides the mark)?

Here's a code snippet

```
# Labels.
sc = plt.scatter(lon, lat, c=temp, s=20, cmap="RdYlGn_r")
for label, xpt, ypt in zip(temp, lon, lat):
    plt.text(xpt + 0.02, ypt, label, ha='left', va='center', color='black')  

    # arrow to the label
    plt.arrow(xpt, ypt, 0.15, 0.15, head_width=0.02, head_length=0.02, fc='black', ec='black')

# add colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc)

# pic layout adjust
plt.tight_layout()


plt.show()
```

Comment: Have a look at `annotate` in the Matplotlib [User Guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/annotations.html) and [API docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrow starts at `(xpt, ypt)` and finishes at `(xpt + 0.15, ypt + 0.15)`.

In order to put the label near the edge, you can offset your text object as such:

```py
plt.text(xpt + dx + 0.02, ypt + dy, label, ha='left', va='center', color='black')
```

where `dx=0.15` and `dy=0.15` in your case.